# Собрать все Node.Checked из TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Есть TreeView с установленным свойством TreeView.CheckBoxes = true, что позволяет выбирать несколько элементов из дерева. Для формирования списка выбранных элементом использую рекурсивный обход дерева, но список остается пустым несмотря на то что элементы в TreeView явно выделены. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
List<string> nodPath = new List<string>();
void CheckedNode(TreeNode tree)
            {
                if (tree.Nodes != null)
                {
                    foreach (TreeNode n in tree.Nodes)
                    {
                        if (n.Checked)
                        {
                            nodPath.Add(n.FullPath);
                        }
                        CheckedNode(n);
                    }
                }
            }
// Вызов
CheckedNode(treeView1.Nodes[0]);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверил Ваш код на примере: [программа](https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/f54333a22fb8f642fbf562675e43a16e), [результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwK97.png). Вроде все работает. Получается, что ошибка в чем-то другом.. Может `nodPath` затирается после, а может `CheckedNode` вызывается до инициализации дерева. Сможете подготовить [вопроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
       void CheckedNode(TreeNode tree)
        {
            if (tree.Checked)
            {
                nodPath.Add(tree.FullPath);
            }

            if (tree.Nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode n in tree.Nodes)
                {                        
                    CheckedNode(n);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Не понял почему первый вариант не работает, но ниже приведенный код делает то что нужно

```
 void Checks(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<TreeNode> list)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                    list.Add(node);

                Checks(node.Nodes, list);
            }
        }

// Вызов
List<TreeNode> listNode = new List<TreeNode>();
Checks(treeView1.Nodes, listNode);

            foreach(TreeNode node in listNode)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(node.FullPath);
            }
```